# I live in a mobile home. The other day my AC stopped working. It does not get cool. I've changed filter, new batteries, switched breaker

Tags: hvac, cooling

I live in a mobile home. AC not cooling. AC about 5 years old. Changed filter, new batteries, checked breaker. Thermostat seems to be working.

Comment: Is the fan blowing air?  Could be a bad start capacitor or compressor.

Comment: Is this a window unit or is it a mini-split?

Comment: There are two motors, one for the fan, one for the compressor.   Do they both run?

Comment: Did the cooling stop suddenly, or did it decrease over time?